# I cannot access the data I want on Express-Gateway

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-gateway

Good work guys.

My project that I developed with Node JS is running at 8001 PORT

```
http://localhost:8001/companies_getAll (return data)
```

I will use EXPRESS-GATEWAY as I want to install a microservice build. However, although I make the settings below, the data is not returned to me.

```
http://localhost:8080/user (return "404 Not Found!")
http://localhost:8080/user/companies_getAll (return "Cannot GET /user/companies_getAll")
```

On the Node JS side, I have such an order.

```
const expressEndpoints = require('./endpoints/main')
expressApplication.use(expressEndpoints)

expressApplication.use((req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send('404 Not Found!')
})

expressApplication.listen(8001, () => {
    console.log('---------------------------------')
    console.log('Running User Service, PORT: 8001')
    console.log('---------------------------------')
})
```

and finally I have such a YAML file.

```
http:
  port: 8080
admin:
  port: 9876
  host: localhost
apiEndpoints:
  api:
    host: localhost
    paths: '/user'
serviceEndpoints:
  user:
    url: 'http://localhost:8001'
policies:
  - basic-auth
  - cors
  - expression
  - key-auth
  - log
  - oauth2
  - proxy
  - rate-limit
  - rewrite
pipelines:
  default:
    apiEndpoints:
      - api
    policies:
      - proxy:
          - action:
              serviceEndpoint: user
              changeOrigin: true
```

I can't get to "companies_getAll". Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

In the [apiEndpoints section](https://www.express-gateway.io/docs/configuration/gateway.config.yml/apiEndpoints/#paths), the path uses an exact match; you’ll need to specify it just in full:

```
paths: '/users/companies_getAll'
```

Or use a wildcard:

```
paths: '/users/*'
```

Or have an array of paths

```
paths:
- '/user'
- '/user/companies_getAll'
```

Comment: Do I need to go there one by one for each api?

Comment: Each path needs to be listed under the paths, somehow. The wildcard can help.